# Bandwidth Management tool

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth, snmp, cacti

There are tools available like `MRTG , Cacti` etc through which we can monitor network traffic  on network interfaces on a host. The network traffic flow information that is provided by these tools is the total traffic that is flowing through the interface . But I want to drill down further like bandwidth classification based on application layer protocols like `HTTP , SMTP , 8080` etc. 
Also , would be great if the tool provides bandwidth classification based on the contributor of traffic . i.e Which IP Address are contributors to incoming and outgoing traffic .

Any tools or plugins to `MRTG , Cacti` etc which provides such information

Comment: Well, I heard the trffic-shephard hardware for doing this. No idea about software part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/) for this. Mike briefly mentions it in his answer, but it seems more of a side note. I personally think ntop is the best candidate.

Ntop is similar to tools like MRTG & Cacti in that it's a long running background process that gathers information and lets you browse through it via a web browser.
It also has a command line mode that has the same feel to it as `top` does for processes.

It can run on an individual host, or you can place it on a gateway server and it can analyze all traffic which flows through the box.
It can show the amount of traffic flowing between 2 hosts, how much data each protocol is using, the currently active sessions, and a lot more.

This screenshot is a bit dated, as they seem to have released a new version with a redesigned UI, but I couldn't find any screenshots of it, and I don't presently have it installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MRTG can display protocol level information [if this is available](http://www.servercare.nl/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=5) from the SNMP sources and configured.

[ipband](http://ipband.sourceforge.net/), [etherape](http://etherape.sourceforge.net/), [netmrg](http://www.netmrg.net/) and [pastmon](http://pastmon.sourceforge.net/Wikka-1.1.6.5/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage) do this out of the box in differing ways.